# Averaging Movie Ratings in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, average, aggregation, create-table

I have a SQL data base comparing different ratings that critics give to movies. I am trying to find the average of the critics' ratings for each unique movie and then create a new table to display these aggregated ratings.

I tried using the AVG(DISTINCT()) functionality, but it only found the averages by distinct ratings, not by distinct movies. Any help with aggregation would be huge!

ETA:
Sample data example

| Movie | Rating |
| --- | --- |
| Jaws | 1 |
| Jaws | 4 |
| Jaws | 3 |
| HomeAlone | 2 |
| HomeAlone | 5 |

Returned data example

| Movie | Rating |
| --- | --- |
| Jaws | 2.67 |
| HomeAlone | 3.5 |

So average all of the individual ratings by the movie name and then create a new table.

Comment: kindly tag the DBMS you are using. that said, while calculating average, remove 'distinct' and add group by movies.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I made the requested edits!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to group by Movie.

```
SELECT Movie, AVG(Rating) FROM [Table] GROUP BY Movie;
```

Comment: That works for creating the correct grouping! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will create the answer you want as the output in a new table

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS 
SELECT Movie, round(AVG(Rating),2) 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Movie;
```